# What is the correct way to set an element type passed as a parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to set a type to element passed as a parameter using `React.ComponentType`.

```js
import * as React from "react"

type BaseType = {
  element: React.ComponentType
}

const Base = ({element: Element}: BaseType) => (
  <Element />
)

const renderBase = (
  Component: React.ComponentType
) => <Base element={Component} />

const Hello = () => renderBase(<h1>Hello</h1>)
```

The error is: `Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{}>'.`

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0wCeYWcAQmlgCpMsC8cAbxpw4WADZYQWAHYwAXJiowAdAGESkaTJjdmNAL51cEaanjtUfOAAoBoiVNkKAog+1x9Ci1x5wAlHC8AHzCcAA8rpLuAPQhNMam8JTSACZYUN6BNurgJtoK2HgqOZraulgBwaFhmeJRsrwCJXmy+nCxRiZmcAAS4mIQWdaVISLJaRkc1mEAFgCMQX1iA2HR80F+QA)

Comment: I believe it is `React.ReactNode` instead of `JSX.Element` or `React.ComponentType`

Comment: @kellys I tried it, but the error change to `JSX element type 'Element' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to pass a JSX element as a prop, you can use the type `JSX.Element`, but you will also have to change `Base`, since `<Element/>` assumes `Element` is a component, not an element. It works if you just return the element itself:

```
type BaseType = {
  element: JSX.Element
}

const Base = ({ element }: BaseType ) => element

const renderBase = (element: JSX.Element) =>
  <Base element={element} />

const Hello = () =>
  renderBase(<h1>Hello</h1>)
```

(I've also renamed `Element` to `element`, to emphasize it's not a component.)

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0wCeYWcAQmlgCpMsC8cAbxpw4WADZYQWAHYwAXHABSAZQAaAOgCiEqbJoBfOrgjTU8dqj5wAFANE6Z8fQotcecAJRxeAPnuTHIxMzOEppABMsKFdvG3EA2QUVDW0EmC9fYTgAHhj43RheAXzHfTgAeh8g03gACXExCFjrDKqRMMjojmtsgAsARh96sUbs8oGfDxogA)

Comment: This is generally a React anti-pattern. The idiomatic way to include already rendered React elements in a component's render tree is to use [`props.children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment).